# latest cppcheck not detecting unused function

Tags: static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I switched to the latest cppcheck and I noticed the following function is not being detected as unused. The old version (1.75) could detect it.

test.cpp

```
#include "test1.h"

using namespace Sample;
void Ctest1::Optiitretch(SOME_ARRAY& arraylist){
#do something
}
```

in test1.h

```
namespace Sample
{

class Ctest1;
typedef std::vector<Ctest1*> SOME_ARRAY;
class Ctest1
{
 static void Optiitretch(SOME_ARRAY& chartList);
}
}
```

Any pointers?

Thanks